# incorrect voltage applied, dev board still worked

Tags: voltage, sensor, board, development

I took this guy from here - http://rlx.sk/en/accelerometer-gyro/3582-vibration-sensor-module-801s-er-sen801svs-.html and without noticing I have applied 3V3 instead of the advertised 5V to it. It also seemed to me it has worked fine. Can anyone tell me why it has still worked or if it makes any difference in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module contains an **extremely** simple circuit:

[image]

The sensor is probably a mechanical one (metal ball or spring) so that works at almost any voltage. The opamp is an LM393 which works form 2 V supply and more.

So there's no reason why it would not work at 3.3 V.

Note however that I personally would not use this circuit as it has issues in its design. There's a reference circuit in the datasheet of the RZ801 which will work much better.

Comment: There is actually some analogueness in there. But this vastly enlightening document from the manufacturer uses a 9V input, so no risk in 5V at least. http://www.tme.eu/nl/Document/f057bde5b9f7ca0c86fbad8e5c5163e5/SENS-801.pdf

Comment: @Asmyldof Do you mean that 4093 circuit is in the sensor module ? I don't think so, I think that it is simply a reference/example circuit and the actual sensor is just a loose/flexible spring used as a switch

Comment: Yes it's the reference circuit for the sensor all the way on the left, which can thus be powered through that same 100k resistor with at least up to 9V. But on their website I found a hilariously confusing/badly-designed example using 50k to 100k and 12V.

Comment: @Asmyldof I really think that that RZ801 is just a metal spring in a metal case. I've seen these in automatic bicycle lights for example. They're extremely cheap yet reliably detect shocks/acceleration. Then 9V, 12 V, 50 k or 100 K does not really matter, it is just a momentary switch.

Comment: Yet the page says there's an "analog out" and the Schematic also shows an "Aout" pin and why running through hoops with coupling capacitors or op-amps if the thing is a switching element? And if it were just a switch, what's the point to the trimming element?

Comment: @Asmyldof It is a crude way of adjusting the detection level. It only sets the timing of the RC (trimpot+C2). If you turn up the pot, you will have to shake a long time before the output responds. Set the pot to 0 ohm and the output responds immediately. It is not a very elegant solution. The senor is switching but the "on" time could be very short, not enough for a human to see a LED light up, the circuit is there to integrate that over time and provide a longer (in time) output signal. Oh I'm talking about the 4093 circuit but you mean the opamp circuit.

Comment: That opamp circuit is indeed questionable, I do not expect the sensitivity pot to work very well. Timing is also fishy with the cap at the output. It's a crappy circuit, that's for sure. I bet that the reference circuit from the RZ801S's datasheet works better.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It is a ball switch, I have read somewhere. `the reference circuit from the RZ801S's datasheet works better` - just a guess or you think that circuit from the datasheet is really better (got no idea myself) ?,

Comment: @kellogs No not a guess, the circuit with the opamp simply does not make a lot of sense to me. The sensitivity setting for example seems to rely on the speed of the opamp which is a weird thing to do. Also the capacitor at the output, no sane circuit designer would do it like that. The 4093 circuit works much better, I've experimented with a similar circuit myself.