# Calibrate/adjust sensitivity of a 801S Vibration Sensor Module

Tags: sensor, calibration, vibration, sensitivity

I have some 801S Vibration Sensor Module I want to use for a project, but I need to make sure they have the same sensitivity. The sensor module has a potentiometer which makes it possible to adjust the sensitivity. I need some help on how to calibrate these sensors.

[image]

You can see additional description about the 801S Vibration Sensor Module here:

https://protosupplies.com/product/801s-vibration-sensor-module/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit in these modules is particularly stupid. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/314533/incorrect-voltage-applied-dev-board-still-worked) answer.

[image]

Note also that the LM393 is open-drain and the pullup is through an LED so that will only get pulled up to 3V-4V. Use a resistor to the supply to get it to pull up higher.

The sensor itself is a mechanical contact that opens so the 'sensitivity' adjust is doing very little except interacting with parasitic capacitance. The sensor ['datasheet'](http://www.tme.eu/nl/Document/f057bde5b9f7ca0c86fbad8e5c5163e5/SENS-801.pdf) contains a reference circuit that makes more sense:

[image]

However note that neither of these circuits really adjust the sensitivity of the sensor, more like the minimum duration of acceleration that exceeds the threshold set by the mechanical sensor.

If you did have something with a genuine sensitivity adjust you'd likely need something like a shaker table to create a consistent level of vibration. I use a small unit ([ET-126](https://www.labworks-inc.com/all_products/shakers/general_purpose/et_126.htm) from Labworks) driven by a power amplifier for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Spehro Pefhany for the nice and complementary answer!

Comment: Would it also be possible to calibrate the sensitivity of the vibration sensor with an accelerometer?

Comment: You need something to create the acceleration, maybe a big woofer